# Unable to run python script remotely through SSH on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, shell, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to implement a networking model(functioning well on ubuntu 14.04) on my system(ubuntu 12.04), which involves connecting with nodes(machines) remotely and running python script on them. For this, I have to run a Python script on 9 remote machines(nodes) using SSH.

```
for ID in $(seq 1 9); do 
    ssh -n -t -t n$ID "sudo ./CONF/conf.py $ID $CONFIG" > /dev/null 2>&1 & 
done
```

However, I guess it gets remotely connected to these machines but somehow not executing the python script on these 9 nodes(machines). 
I checked the same experiment in the other system(ubuntu 14.04) where it functions properly to compare the difference and it did execute the python script on each node there and we can see it in the background process. The left screen is from my system and right is from other system(ubuntu 14.04)

The left screen is from my system and right is from other system(ubuntu 14.04):

[image: The left screen is from my system and right is from other system(ubuntu 14.04):]

Also, I tried connecting to separate machines using ssh and then running separate python script on them. Python script gets executed successfully there. But somehow, using a single command for 9 machines is not working.

What possibly could I be missing on my system(ubuntu 12.04) while the same model runs perfectly on the other(ubuntu 14.04)???

Comment: Do you have an error message or is it failing silently?

Comment: It is failing silently. I didn't get any error message. But it did work in the other system as I mentioned above. I have created the same setup as is present in the other system(ubuntu 14.04) for running this model, but somehow, something fails the python script execution.

Comment: The cumulative processes running on target machines are shown in the screenshot. For example, the process running on machine 1 should be the processes with status Ss+ and R+ as shown in the screenshot. Same with machine 2.3... However, on my system the process with status R+ is somehow not running.